# Post processing gmapping generated maps to add glass wall information

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gmapping system misses glass surfaces since it makes use of laser data. Unfortunately, we have an environment that has quite a few glass walls/doors. Has anyone run into this issue? If yes, how do you folks suggest we handle it? I can always modify the map manually in an image editor. Is there a better way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72160/post-processing-gmapping-generated-maps-to-add-glass-wall-information/) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a related question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/66083/local-navigation-with-additional-rescrictions/), which links to some answers. The problem is that if these glass walls are actually invisible in the laser scan, the local trajectory planner can still try to go through them, even if you manually paint the walls into the global map. So you'll need something like layered costmaps which contain the "no go zones".

Or you could do what we did with our (small) glass door, which is stick a couple sheets of paper onto it at a certain height... :-)

Or try additionally using an ultrasound ranger for local obstacle avoidance, if your robot happens to have one (not tried, but should work).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-08-12**:
Thanks for your answer :). We thought of covering up glass surfaces already. The problem is that our environment is an entire floor of the building, and covering up all the glass surfaces will be tedious. I was hoping I can somehow detect glass and augment the maps.

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-08-12**:
(I've observed that the laser does seem to detect glass when incidence is near normal.)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Traditionally people have just drawn in a line in an image editor. You probably want to make the line thin as possible so that it has the least effect possible on other components, like AMCL, or, possibly give an unedited map to AMCL for localization.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1